# editing the padding to vertically align buttons and brand icons in the navbar

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-material-design

I am trying to create a customized navbar that uses buttons for the nav-items. When the window is in fullscreen (on PC Chrome), the buttons I have do not align vertically with the icon I placed in the navbar-brand (pic below). Additionally, when the window is minimized, the dropdown menu does not react or show my buttons.

[Fullscreen website with misaligned buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1VBW.jpg)

Here is the Codeply for reference:
[CodeWizard -7/14/2020](https://codeply.com/v/IsYK0OGkuL)

edit: the CSS used is bootstrap and bootstrap material design

Comment: When the window is minimized, you could access the same navbar buttons using the menu icon at the top-right position.. right?

Comment: The codepen shared by you has buttons vertically centered with respect to the icon.What css have you used ?

Comment: @TanuArora, I am using bootstrap 4, and bootstrap material design

Comment: @aks44, no, the menu icon does trigger any drop-down menu to show the navbar buttons